# Android fragment communication

Tags: java, android

i would like to have communication between fragments in sliding menu but in my code `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag` returns null.
I've searched and noticed i have to use `executePendingTransactions()` after `commit()` (if i'm right) .
but i got this error :

```
529-529/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 529
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

i am using `android.app.Fragment` not `support package` .
please help me.

this is my mainActivity code:

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
GoodsFragment gf= new GoodsFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, gf, "gf");
ft.addToBackStack("gf");
ft.commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();

gf = (GoodsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gf");
if(gf != null)
    {
        gf.setText(msg);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Sending Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

GoodsFragment code:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_goods, container, false);
   TextView txtcheckbox =  (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   txtcheckbox.setText("some thing...");

   return rootView;   }

void setText(String msg)
{
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTextView.setText(msg);
}
```

BridgeFragment code:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bridge, container, false);

    onButtonClicked(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
    protected void onButtonClicked(View view)
{

    msg ="ghazaleh arabi";
    sendMessage();
}

interface StartCommunication
{
    public void setComm(String msg);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(activity instanceof StartCommunication)
    {
        mStartCommunicationListner = (StartCommunication)activity;
    }
    else
        throw new ClassCastException();

}
```

Comment: try this way:  Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gf");
if (fragment instanceof GoodsFragment) {
}

Comment: thank you but it returns null again.also i comment this line fm.executePendingTransactions(); to execute.

Comment: are you using fragment inside other fragment?

Comment: no . i have sliding menu .

Comment: try using childFragmentmanager instead of FragmentManager

Comment: can not use  childFragmentmanager  in mainActivity .It gets can not resolve method.I think childFragmentmanager  uses in fragment page.Am i right?

Comment: Why are you looking up a `Fragment` that you just created? Can't you just comment the "gf = (GoodsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gf");" line?

Comment: because i want to call setText from goodsfragment when i comment that line i got nullpointer error from rootview in this line in goods fragment:void setText(String msg)
{
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTextView.setText(msg);
}

Comment: What you are trying to do, should be done passing arguments through bundle to fragment. Read http://gunhansancar.com/best-practice-to-instantiate-fragments-with-arguments-in-android/

Comment: Thanks again . It's a better way.@ManpreetSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of FragmentTransaction, commit method:

`Schedules a commit of this transaction.  The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.`

Here you are trying to do findFragmentByTag immediately after commit and transaction might not have been committed by then. So in the current scenario, if you will give some wait before it should work.

Comment: so how can i give some wait before it . i have used fm.executePendingTransactions(); but this line gets error:Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Comment: Removing the addToBackStack should make fm.executePendingTransactions() to work, you can try and let me know. 

And for wait you can use handler, `(new Handler()).postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`

Comment: I removed the addToBackStack but fm.executePendingTransactions() does not work yet.

Comment: also add tese lines after commit :  Runnable r = new Runnable()
  {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {

   }
  };
  new Handler().postDelayed(r, 500 ); but no changes . am i doing right?

Comment: write your code inside run method i.e Runnable r = new Runnable() { @Override public void run(){gf = (GoodsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gf");
if(gf != null)
    {
        gf.setText(msg);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Sending Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

It will work

Comment: i did it . i get this: can not find local variable gf , msg and get error from makeText! why it doesn't find variable?!!! sorry i'm new in android :-(

Comment: I can make this work for you. But you need a lot of learning here.

First is you have to write 'final' ahead of gf and msg variables and replace 'this' in makeText with 'MainActivity.this'

Comment: thank you.ok sure.i made gf as a final variable but final is constant and will not change.it gets error again : gf = (GoodsFragment)  
 getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gf");

Comment: Yes. So Use a new variable and declare it inside the braces

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much  for tolerating my questions. it's solved .you helped me so much :-)

Comment: Great. As I said above in question's comment, the right way to do what you are doing is by passing arguments to the fragment in the bundle using setArguments() method. I hope you will look into that. And please choose this answer as the right answer as it solved your problem.